# How to restrict time Linux takes for an action?

Tags: c++, linux, time, raspberry-pi, real-time

Question can look blurry since it's hard to describe a problem in one line so here it goes.
I use Debian on Raspberry Pi to run a PID regulator which means dt(time difference between loop executions) is obtained every time PID output is calculated.
Basically dt is calculated like this.

```
    oldtime_ = time_;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_);
    Timer.dt = ((static_cast<int64_t>(time_.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + static_cast<int64_t>(time_.tv_nsec)) - (static_cast<int64_t>(oldtime_.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + static_cast<int64_t>(oldtime_.tv_nsec))) / 1000000000.0;
```

PID is updated around 400 times a second and it goes just fine, but sometimes Linux decides to take much more time to make an action. The result is a large number of dt, say, not 1/400 = 0.0025 but a 0.8 which is 320 times more than needed. 
The result is incorrect calculation of PID. That looks like this.
[image]

I'd love to have an answer how to move raspbian a little bit closer to a real time system.

**EDIT**

Thanks, anaken78 and anyone who've helped. Using RR_FIFO schedule worked perfectly and processing speed is always aroud 380-400hz. 
[image]

Comment: If you need a high precision, cheap timer, I suggest to use the TSC directly (if available), and pin your process to a single core (if the system is multicore) to avoid TSC skew.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not like this requirement is totally new an unique, and you already seem to know the keywords to search for. Also, is the timer not precise or does the scheduler mess with your logic?

Comment: System is single cored itself. The problem is scheduler messing up so I'm not sure if using TSC directly  would help, but I'll give it a try if operating TSC directly gives a higher priority to a scheduler. As I said, question looks blurry for me to google. The only keyword I've tried is "real-time", but I haven't used RTlinux or real-time kernels just yet. I'll do this if dancing around debian gives no results.

Comment: I had an idea of using system signals to launch PID processing every X nanoseconds, but I'm still not sure if scheduler wouldn't mess with that as well.

Comment: Linux will never become a full-blown hard real-time OS, but since last year, it has a hard-rt-style scheduling type, SCHED_DEADLINE. For high-precision timers, you may look into tickless kernel. Basically, that allows the kernel to schedule timer interrupts anytime, instead of 1000 or 100 times per second (typical values for HZ). BTW, when I tried nanosleep() last week on a vanilla kernel, I got sleeps down to ~60 microseconds, without using tickless.

Comment: Should mention kernel version, it was (K)ubuntu 3.16 linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the original Raspberry pi and not the Raspberry pi 2. The problem with original Raspberry pi is that it uses a single core ARM11 cpu which effectively means that any kind of RT calculation (the way you are doing) are bound to have errors because of hardware interrupts. For e.g., packets coming over the Wifi might interrupt your system, which will cause a problem.

One possible thing you could try, if you are fine with having no network connectivity, is to increase your process priority and shut down your wifi and eth interfaces. These, I would say, are the main sources of asynchronous interrupts that might end up disrupting your process execution. There will be other interrupts that keep firing, you can look at /proc/interrupts and /proc/softirq to get an idea of the interrupts firing, but in a platform like raspberry pi, they should either be priodic (timer) or they will very short lived (for e.g. USB interrupts) shouldn't cause lags in your process, to the order of a few ms.